# Tag a Sentence based on Tagged Sentences

Tags: python, nlp, tagging

I am creating a system capable of tag a sentence based on a previous tagged sentences. I have a corpora with the structure as the **Known Questions**.

**Known Questions:**

> *city_name* What are the most popular city in spain?
>
> *amount_of_people* How many people are in the city center?

**New questões:**

> What are the most popular city in Italy?
>
> How many people are in the at the stadium?
>
> What is the nearest city to New York?

**Example of tags:**

> *city_name*
>
> *amount_of_people*

**desired result:**

> *city_name* What are the most popular city in Italy?
>
> *amount_of_people* How many people are in the at the stadium?
>
> *city_name* What is the nearest city to New York?

I have in total 30 tags and 350 Senteces.
is there any python framework or an known algorithm to analyze the corpora and tag a new sentence base on the corpora ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this ought to be treated as the machine learning task of classification. You could use any number of [approaches](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/a-comprehensive-guide-to-understand-and-implement-text-classification-in-python/) starting from Naive Bayes to Multilayer Perceptron to softmax based DNNs. I would strongly suggest using one of the above for such tasks, but given that you have only 350 questions, I have no idea if classifiers can learn on so little data without experimenting.

However, if you wish to approach this using rule-based methods, I would suggest using [dependency parsing](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.html). This is under the assumption that all your data consists of grammatically well-formed questions, and that there is a semantic relation between the tags and the questions.

Let's use the Stanford Dependency Parser [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/) for the question: `What is the nearest city to New York?`.

```
UNIVERSAL DEPENDENCIES:

root(ROOT-0, What-1)
cop(What-1, is-2)
det(city-5, the-3)
amod(city-5, nearest-4)
nsubj(What-1, city-5)
case(York-8, to-6)
compound(York-8, New-7)
nmod(city-5, York-8)
```

As you can see, the `nsubj` (nominal subject) tells us about the relation between 'What' and 'city' (understand more about the dependencies [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf)). So every time, you have 'city' as `nsubj` of 'what' (say), you could allocate the `city_name` tag to the question.

Similarly, if 'people' is in the `nsubj` of a question (and 'many' in the `amod`), maybe you could allocate the `amount_of_people` tag to that question.

You'd have to observe and find the best dependency based rules for each of the 30 tags in a similar manner, and that should definitely do the trick.

Comment: but in the case of How many people are in the at the stadium?, I will have nsubj(are-4, people-3), how can I detect the amount_of_people tag ?
thanks for the awnser!

Comment: Like I mentioned in the answer, you could use adverb or adjectival modifiers. In this case, dependency `amod(people-3, many-2)` indicates that `people` is being modified by `many`. Similarly the dependency `advmod(many-2, How-1)` gives you information, too. You need to leverage that.

Comment: @NoBody take a look at this meta [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119197/problem-with-users-not-accepting-answers), please. It would be nice for new users to get motivation to answer more posts. Either downvote answers if they don't help when people aren't answering comments for those posts, or upvote/accept if they help.